# what is proper way to use jquery in angular js directives?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have been developed code of angular directive with jQuery but I am not confident that is it proper way to use jQuery in directive or not.

Definitely there may be another ways but I don't know. can anyone guide me about proper way or give me improvement suggestion of to develop directive and user jQuery in this directive and am I doing wrong if I used jQuery validate plug-in to perform validation of angular js form.?

Hope for some guidelines and improved suggestions.

Thank you...

## directive:

```
    (function(){
        'use strict';
        angular
        .module("App")
        .directive("signInPopup",function(){
            return {
                templateUrl: "/views/auth/signin.html",
                restrict: 'E',
                controller: function(){
                    console.log("signin controller called");
                },
                scope: '=',
                replace: true,
                compile: function(element, attrs){
                    return {
                        pre: function(scope, element, attrs){
                            $(".popup-modal").magnificPopup({
                                type : 'inline',
                                preloader : true,
                                // focus: '#username',
                                modal : true,
                                callbacks : {
                                    beforeClose : function(e) {
                                        console.log("jquery called in before close");
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                            $(".tab_content").hide();
                            $(".tab_content:first").show();
                            $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
                                $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
                                $(this).addClass("active");
                                $(".tab_content").hide();
                                var activeTab = $(this).attr("rel");
                                $("#" + activeTab).fadeIn();
                            });
                            $('.tabs-container li a').click(function() {
                                $('.tabs-container li a ').removeClass('active');
                                $(this).addClass('active');
                            });

                            $("#frmSignup").validate({
                                wrapper: 'div',
                                rules:{
                                    txtFullname: {
                                        required: true,
                                        maxlength: 50
                                    },
                                    txtNickname: {
                                        required: true,
                                        maxlength: 25
                                    },
                                    txtEmail: {
                                        required: true,
                                        email: true,
                                        maxlength: 150,
                                        remote: {
                                            url: "/api/user/checkEmail",
                                            type: "post",
                                            data: {
                                              email: function() {
                                                return $( "#txtEmail" ).val();
                                              }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    txtPassword:{
                                        required: true,
                                        minlength: 8,
                                        pattern:'//'
                                    },
                                    txtConfirmPassword:{
                                        required: true,
                                        equalTo: 'txtPassword'
                                    },
                                    chkTermsAndConditions:{
                                        required: true
                                    }
                                },
                                messages:{
                                    txtFullname:{
                                        required: 'Fullname is required',
                                        maxlength: 'Maximum 50 characters length exceed'
                                    },
                                    txtNickname: {
                                        required: 'Nickname is required',
                                        maxlength: 'Maximum 25 characters length exceed'
                                    },
                                    txtEmail: {
                                        required: 'Email is required',
                                        email: 'Email is invalid',
                                        maxlength: 'Email length exceed to maximum 150 characters'
                                    },
                                    txtPassword:{
                                        required: 'Password is required',
                                        minlength: 'Password minimum length must be 8 characters'
                                    },
                                    txtConfirmPassword:{
                                        required: 'Confirm password is required',
                                        equalTo: 'Confirm password must same as password'
                                    },
                                    chkTermsAndConditions:{
                                        required: 'You must accept terms and conditions'
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        },
                        post: function(scope, element, attrs){}
                    }
                },
                link: function(scope, element, attrs){
                }
            }
        });

    }());
```

## Signin.html

```
<div id='signup-modal' class='login-popup login-popup-new mfp-hide'>
<div class='tabs-container'>
    <ul class='tabs-frame tabs'>
        <li class='active' rel='tab1'>
            <a id='sign_in_tab' class='first reset_frm active' href='javascript:void(0)' class='active first'>Signin</a>
        </li>
         <li rel='tab2'>
            <a id='sign_in_tab' class='reset_frm' href='javascript:void(0)' class=''>Signup</a>
        </li>
         <li rel='tab3'>
            <a id='sign_in_tab' class='reset_frm' href='javascript:void(0)' class=''>Forgot password</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class='tabs-frame-content tab_content' id='tab2' ng-controller='SignupCtrl'>
        <div id='user_signup'>
            <form name='frmSignup' id='frmSignup' ng-click="doRegistration(frmSignup.$valid)" autocomplete='off' name='frmSignup' novalidate>
                <div class='content'>
                    <label class='formlabel1'>Fullname</label>
                    <input type='text' name='txtFullname' id='txtFullname' class='inputbox inputbox_width' ng-model='user.txtFullname' ng-required='true'/>

                    <label class='formlabel1'>Nickname</label>
                    <input type='text' name='txtNickname' id='txtNickname' class='inputbox inputbox_width' ng-model='user.txtNickname'  ng-required`='true'/>

                    <label class='formlabel1'>Email</label>
                    <input type='email' name='txtEmail' id='txtEmail' class='inputbox inputbox_width' ng-model='user.txtEmail'  ng-required='true'/>

                    <label class='formlabel1'>Password</label>
                    <input type='text' name='txtPassword' id='txtPassword' class='inputbox inputbox_width' ng-model='user.txtPassword'  ng-required='true'/>

                    <label class='formlabel1'>Cofirm password</label>
                    <input type='text' name='txtConfirmPassword' id='txtConfirmPassword' class='inputbox inputbox_width' ng-model='user.txtConfirmPassword'  ng-required='true'/>

                    <div class='chkbox_signup'>
                        <input type='checkbox' id='chkTermsAndConditions' name='chkTermsAndConditions' ng-model='chkTermsAndConditions' value='1' ng-model='user.chkTermsAndConditions'  ng-required='true'/>

                        <label for='User_terms_condition' class='checkbox font-weight-normal'>
                        &nbsp;I read&nbsp;<a target='_blank' href='/'>terms &amp; conditions</a>&nbsp;and&nbsp;<a target='_blank' href='/'>privacy policies</a>&nbsp;carefully.
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="actions button-groups login-button-space">
                    <input type='button' value='Cancel' name='btnCancel' id='btnCancel' class='popup-modal-dismiss submit-btn button pull-right sp1' ng-model='user.btnCancel'/>
                    <input type='submit' name='btnRegister' id='btnRegister' class='submit-btn button pull-right sp1' value='Register' ng-model='user.btnRegister'  />
                    <div class='clearfix'></div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [“Thinking in AngularJS” if I have a jQuery background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)

Comment: The question isn't so much how to use jQuery, but whether you should be toggling element classes and states using Angular's built-in directives based on your model, rather than manually.

Comment: Isherwood actually I am trying to use jquery but I didn't confident that how could I use it, before add jquery code in compile, I tried another way but it didn't work. So it works in compile at the end but I don't confident so I tried to post and hope to get some good suggestion and knowledge. Hope you may getting my aspect to post a question.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to make use of `jQuery`, then make sure that jQuery library has been referenced before than that of AngularJS's.

This is necessary step to avoid AngularJS making use of `jqLite`.

Once that has been done, one can use any of the following syntaxes for using jQuery -:

HTML:

```
<div class="customClass"></div>
```

JS:

1.

```
  $('.customClass')
```

2.

```
  jQuery('.customClass')
```

3.

```
  var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $j('.customClass');
```

4.

```
 angular.element('.customClass');
```

The first three are `jQuery` way and the fouth one is the AngularJS way.

Comment: thank you for your answer. But I had tried same thing but I didn't succeed so I can do this way. Please review my previous question :  [My posted question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36058749/how-to-integrate-jquery-magnific-popup-by-custom-angularjs-directive.) i didn't get any answer so I had implement jquery in this way.

Comment: If I didin't put jquery code in compile this way then it will not work any more.

Answer (score 0):

I know I had similar question and didn't got a straight answer. Have a look here. Might help a bit.

https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-application-wiring-jquery-vs-angularjs

IF you plan using Angular best is to go Angular way and avoid using jQuery if Angular provides similar functions.